# Providing customers with domain aliasing

Tags: heroku, dns, domain-aliasing

Currently I have an app which gives my users a custom subdomain.

neat.coolapp.com

However, I want my users to be able to CNAME their personal domain to that website.
ex. hey.neat.com -> neat.coolapp.com

Is this possible on heroku?

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add whatever domain the customer wants to use to your application so the correct application on Heroku responds - you could do this either manually (via the heroku control panel) or use the heroku gem within your application to add the domain to your application via some kind of control panel if the customer is able to add their own domains.

In regards to cname's - I would suggest setting up something like `proxy.yourwebsite.com` as a CNAME to `yourapp.heroku.com` and then you get your customers to cname their domain to `proxy.yourwebsite.com` in their DNS config.

Answer (score 0):

When you sign up for Heroku you will get a subdomain like

`asdf.heroku.com`

If you have a domain like `mywebsite.com` you can cname `mywebsite.com` to `asdf.heroku.com` and you will need to add `mywebsite.com` to Heroku's custom domain command.

From there I'm not sure, if you wanted to add `mywebsite2.com` without having to add it using the custom domain command you can try to cname it to `mywebsite.com`, if you have two domains you can try it out.